# App crash when I use the Branch framework

Tags: ios, swift, branch.io, slcomposeviewcontroller

I use the Branch SDK for deep links to the iOS application. The problem appears in the following cases if you send a deep link to a third-party application (for example, Slack, Facebook) quickly, then an app crash occurs. The console shows the following result `[core] SLComposeViewController dealloc <SLComposeViewController: 0x11fbf03a0>.` How can I fix it?

My code

```
func shareCardDetail(_ cardModel: CardModel) {
        let shareText = "What do you think about this?"
        let branchUniversalObject = BranchUniversalObject(canonicalIdentifier: ("cardId/\(cardModel.id)"))
        branchUniversalObject.title = cardModel.title
        branchUniversalObject.contentDescription = ""
        branchUniversalObject.imageUrl = cardModel.photoURLsProperties.placeVenuePhoto

        branchUniversalObject.addMetadataKey(CardKeys.cardID.rawValue, value: cardModel.id)

        if let placeAvatarURLString = cardModel.photoURLsProperties.placeVenuePhoto {
            branchUniversalObject.addMetadataKey("placeAvatarURLString", value: placeAvatarURLString)
        }
        branchUniversalObject.addMetadataKey("title", value: cardModel.title)
        branchUniversalObject.addMetadataKey("isAutoGeneratedCard", value: "false")

        let fullLocationName = cardModel.location.fullLocationName
        branchUniversalObject.addMetadataKey("fullLocationName", value: fullLocationName)

        branchUniversalObject.addMetadataKey(CardKeys.ownerID.rawValue, value: cardModel.ownerID)
        branchUniversalObject.addMetadataKey(ParametersKeywords.type.rawValue, value: ModeKeywords.shareCard.rawValue)

        branchUniversalObject.addMetadataKey("availableSeats", value: cardModel.peopleProperties.availableSeats.description)

        if let coordinate = cardModel.location.coordinate {
            branchUniversalObject.addMetadataKey("latitude", value: coordinate.latitude.description)
            branchUniversalObject.addMetadataKey("longitude",value: coordinate.longitude.description)
        }


        let linkProperties = BranchLinkProperties()
        linkProperties.feature = "sharing"
        linkProperties.addControlParam("$desktop_url", withValue: "http://www.example.com")
        linkProperties.addControlParam("$ios_url", withValue: "example://")

        guard let topViewController = UIApplication.topViewController() else { return }

        branchUniversalObject.showShareSheet(with: linkProperties, andShareText: shareText, from: topViewController) { (text, success) in
            debugPrint("done showing share sheet!")
        }
    }
```

[image]

Comment: Please add a stack trace from the crash.

Comment: @ravron I updated my post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed my code and it works.

```
func shareCardDetail(_ cardModel: CardModel) {
        let shareText = "What do you think about this?"
        let branchUniversalObject = BranchUniversalObject(canonicalIdentifier: ("cardId/\(cardModel.id)"))
        branchUniversalObject.title = cardModel.title
        branchUniversalObject.contentDescription = ""
        branchUniversalObject.imageUrl = cardModel.photoURLsProperties.placeVenuePhoto

        branchUniversalObject.addMetadataKey(CardKeys.cardID.rawValue, value: cardModel.id)

        if let placeAvatarURLString = cardModel.photoURLsProperties.placeVenuePhoto {
            branchUniversalObject.addMetadataKey("placeAvatarURLString", value: placeAvatarURLString)
        }
        branchUniversalObject.addMetadataKey("title", value: cardModel.title)
        branchUniversalObject.addMetadataKey("isAutoGeneratedCard", value: "false")

        let fullLocationName = cardModel.location.fullLocationName
        branchUniversalObject.addMetadataKey("fullLocationName", value: fullLocationName)

        branchUniversalObject.addMetadataKey(CardKeys.ownerID.rawValue, value: cardModel.ownerID)
        branchUniversalObject.addMetadataKey(ParametersKeywords.type.rawValue, value: ModeKeywords.shareCard.rawValue)

        branchUniversalObject.addMetadataKey("availableSeats", value: cardModel.peopleProperties.availableSeats.description)

        if let coordinate = cardModel.location.coordinate {
            branchUniversalObject.addMetadataKey("latitude", value: coordinate.latitude.description)
            branchUniversalObject.addMetadataKey("longitude",value: coordinate.longitude.description)
        }


        let linkProperties = BranchLinkProperties()
        linkProperties.feature = "sharing"
        linkProperties.addControlParam("$desktop_url", withValue: "http://www.example.com")
        linkProperties.addControlParam("$ios_url", withValue: "example://")

        guard let topViewController = UIApplication.topViewController() else { return }


        guard let branchShareLink = BranchShareLink(universalObject: branchUniversalObject, linkProperties: linkProperties) else { return }
        branchShareLink.shareText = shareText
        branchShareLink.presentActivityViewController(from: topViewController, anchor: nil)
    }
```